# How to add base URI in RestTemplate

Tags: spring, resttemplate

Is there any other way to initialize RestTemplate  with base URI other than
extending RestTemplate and overriding the execute method.currently i have the code like below.Thanks

```
class CustomRestTemplate extends RestTemplate {
String baseUrl

@Override
protected  T doExecute(URI url, HttpMethod method, RequestCallback requestCallback, ResponseExtractor responseExtractor) throws RestClientException {
    return super.doExecute(new URI(baseUrl + url.toString()), method, requestCallback, responseExtractor)
}
```

Answer (score 56):

Spring 5.0:

This sends a GET request to `http://localhost:8080/myservice`

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.setUriTemplateHandler(new DefaultUriBuilderFactory("http://localhost:8080"));
restTemplate.getForObject("/myservice", String.class);
```

Answer (score 28):

If you are using Spring Boot, you can use `org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder.rootUri(baseUrl).build()`

Comment: looks like it does not work when you try to update the `baseUrl` String using Spring's `@Value`

Answer (score 12):

You can create your custom `DefaultUriTemplateHandler`

```
DefaultUriTemplateHandler defaultUriTemplateHandler = new DefaultUriTemplateHandler();
defaultUriTemplateHandler.setBaseUrl(url);
```

And then add it to `restTemplate`

```
return new RestTemplateBuilder()
      .uriTemplateHandler(defaultUriTemplateHandler)
      .build();
```

Comment: DefaultUriTemplateHandler has been Deprecated as of 5.0 in favor of DefaultUriBuilderFactory. So we should avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

Spring's `RestTemplate` (version 4.2.0.RELEASE) support a method named `setUriTemplateHandler`. If this is never set, it contains a `DefaultUriTemplateHandler`

`DefaultUriTemplateHandler` supports a method named 'setBaseUrl`

So, you can set the base URL there.

Answer (score -7):

AFAIK there is no way other than what you have listed above